# c# for a group of objects get property and ensure same value for all

Tags: c#, linq

Hi say I have a class PaymentGroup, a PaymentGroup has a List of Payments. Each payment has a code.

The rule is that all Payments within a group must have the same code.

I want to somehow get the Code for a PaymentGroup but if the Payments within a PaymentGroup do not all have the same Code throw an exception.

The code I have so far is a property in PaymentGroup:

```
public Code
{
  get
  {
    var codesTheSame = Payments.Select(x => x.Code)
                              .Distinct()
                              .Count() == 1;

    if(!codesTheSame)
      throw Exception();

    return Payments.First().Code;
  }
}
```

I'm thinking this could be written more cleanly but I haven't come up with any alternatives.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, could you accept one of the answers or do you need more advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not something like:

```
public Code
{
    get {
        return Payments.Select(x => x.Code)
                              .Distinct()
                              .Single();
    }
}
```

This will throw an **InvalidOperationException** with the message "*Sequence contains more than one element*" in case it contains more than 1 code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstCode = Payments.First().Code;

if (Payments.Any(p => p.Code != firstCode))
    throw Exception();

return firstCode;
```

This will terminate early if it finds a Payment which doesn't match the first, and if all Codes are the same, it won't have to enumerate Payments again.

Answer (score 0):

```
var groups = Payments.GroupBy(p => p.Code).ToList();
if(groups.Count > 1) throw new Exception("Multiple codes in group");
else if(groups.Count == 1) return groups[0].Key
else {
    //Payments is empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just go back to basics (assuming you meant an actual List<Payment>):

```
var code = Payments[0].Code;
for (int i = 1; i < Payments.Count; i++) {
    if (Payments[i].Code != code) {
         throw new Exception();
    }
}
return code;
```